# Is Logic supposed to lose my work on Command-W?

Tags: macos, keyboard, logic

Twice today I've accidentally hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> while editing in Logic.  Both times the project window closed without prompting me to save my work.  The work was lost both times.  If I go to *File > Quit*, it will ask me if I want to save, but not when I press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>.

Is this a bug, and is there a setting I can change to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

### No.

In the [Key commands for Global Commands in Logic Pro for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcp02bf31b6/mac)
 Apple Support article, it is stated that the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut closes the active window (without any mention to saving changes).

And in the [Close projects in Logic Pro for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcpce0e7a31/mac) Apple Support article, it is said that:

> The Close Project without Saving key command **closes the currently active project without saving it—and you will not be asked to do so**. This command was included at the request of many experienced Logic Pro users. Only use it if you’re sure that this is what you want to do.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

The keyboard shortcut to close a project and being prompted to save it is  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> (explicitly mentioned in the second Apple Support article), so (logically), <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> closes the active window without prompting you to save it.

---

> Is there a setting I can change to prevent this?

### Yes.

You can just modify the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut to something more complicated to type to avoid you accidentally pressing it.

To do this, go to Logic Pro's settings (you can use the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut) and, in the "Key Commands" tab, search for the "Close Window" command using the search bar. Locate the "Close Window" command in the list and double-click the keyboard shortcut associated with it (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> by default).

A pop-up window should appear, click on the "Learn by Key Label" button, press (with your keyboard) the new keyboard shortcut you want to use for closing windows and saving changes (e.g. <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>) and click "OK".

**Note:** Modifying keyboard shortcuts in Logic Pro (as well as in any app) may affect other commands, so it's important to choose a keyboard shortcut ***that doesn't conflict with existing ones***.

Answer (score 3):

I use Logic on 2 Macs, and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> will prompt for a save if I've modified something.

System Settings has no modified key commands, and **Ask to keep changes when closing documents** is OFF.

However, Logic has its own Key Command Assignment dialog. I don't know if I've modified this, but here's what I have:

[image]

I can't find any other suitable candidates for settings, but there must be reason why it doesn't happen for you.